# Returning data through controller without going through view using json string

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm a beginner to this codeigniter. The question is, how can i return the data through controller alone without going through the view. Is there any possibility i can achieve it using this json technique. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a browser output then you may `echo` the whole html in your controller, which is not subtle.

If you want to process data before output, then you may just use the [codeigniter output class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html)

If you are trying to return a json string back to a cross domain request, then you can simply use `return` statement to do that.

If you want to get an ajax result from a controller function, then just `return` a json string or `echo` the data from the controller like a normal php ajax page

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the JSON data Like this. all the following method in your controller.

Test by opening `root/index.php/Controller/display_json/`

```
public function display_json()
{
    // Sample JSON Data 
    $json_data = "[ { 'Name': 'S0Name', 'City': 'S0City', 'Country': 'S0Country' },
                    { 'Name': 'S1Name', 'City': 'S1City', 'Country': 'S1Country' },
                    { 'Name': 'S2Name', 'City': 'S2City', 'Country': 'S2Country' },
                    { 'Name': 'S3Name', 'City': 'S3City', 'Country': 'S3Country' },
                    { 'Name': 'S4Name', 'City': 'S4City', 'Country': 'S4Country' },
                    { 'Name': 'S5Name', 'City': 'S5City', 'Country': 'S5Country' } ]";
    echo ($json_data);
}
```

You have to make a string that like a JSON Data Format.

Also if data is from database, you still have to make them like JSON Data Format.